# Taking an indirect reference in Excel and making it a direct reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For many somewhat complicated reasons – it has to do with transposing columns and rows because of third party software limitations, etc. – I have had to use the `INDIRECT` function in order to make copying a formula across a range of cells feasible. However, I would like to make the references direct.
Consider the following example:

[image]

in which a cell (`B2` in the example) contains `=INDIRECT(A2)`,
and cell `A2` contains the text value `B1`.
Thus, cell `B2` evaluates to `=INDIRECT("B1")`;
i.e., it fetches the value from cell `B1`.

Is there anyway to actually change `=INDIRECT(A2)` to just `=B1`?

Comment: You could have a macro transforming indirect functions to their actual value. Is that kind of a solution you are looking for?

Comment: VBA will be the way to do this. I mean it's possible using a bunch of formulas, but not easy.

Comment: @shA.t: What are you talking about?  I don't know any more behind information or inside information or whatever than you do,  But I think the requirement is comprehensible — the OP has a large spreadsheet (or workbook) that contains many indirect references (as shown) and wants to replace them with equivalent direct references *en masse* in an automated way.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a little long winded but it's a way I know how to complete this. I'll use your example.

The first thing to do is replace INDIRECT with `"="&`
You can do this using find and replace if you have many cells or just in the formula bar for the example above.

The cell should now return `=B1`

Copy and paste special as values so it's no longer a formula.

The cell will show =B1 but won't resolve as 2 yet. Do a find and replace for = with =.

I know your just replacing a character with the same character but Excel will now return the result of the formula correctly

That should work for your situation.